# How to transform a tree-form list to matrix-form list in Mathematica?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, data-structures, trees

Excuse my naive question. Is there a quick/efficient way to transform

```
{{1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}
```

to a lower-triangular matrix-form

```
{{1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 3, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}
```

Just looking for an idea, but a sample code or an educational reference are also appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `PadRight[#, 4] & /@ {{1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}`. I assumed there was a typo in your matrix (there are five elements in the third list of your desired output).

Comment: Actually, just plain `PadRight[{{1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}]` works!

Comment: @J.M. The very last usage case in the help docs: `pads a ragged array list with zeros to make it full.` Never even noticed!

Comment: Great comments. Please place them as answers I can favor.